# making drop-list, mouse-over mouse-out issue

Tags: javascript

[image: kdfnlf]

I want when passing the cursor over the icon on the left the the `div` `droplist` on the right appear. I could manage to do this but when move the cursor out of the icon the `div` disappears and it should only disappears when move the mouse out of the `div`

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function showDrop(){
     document.getElementById('droplist').style.display="block";
   }
   function hideDrop(){
     document.getElementById('droplist').style.display="none";
   }

</script>


 <div id="droplist"  onmouseout="hideDrop()" style="background:#800000;border:1px solid #000000;position:absolute;display:none;">
     <img src="images/stats.png"/><br>
     <div >
        <input type="button" value="phone num" ><br>
        <input type="button" value="fax num" >
     </div>
 </div>

 <img src="images/stats.png" onmouseover="showDrop()"/>
```

### update

I discovered that the event `onmouseout` on the div `droplist` will make every element,  inside the `div`, act if the event on it

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer did a good thing once and thought of the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. From what I've read briefly, they're not reliably implemented by older/other browsers (citation needed!).

Before pulling teeth, I used the YUI (Yahoo User Interface) Javascript library to handle that all for me.

Here's a link on how to use the 2 events: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/mouseenter.html

It's very handy trick to have up your sleeve - if you're able to use 3rd party JS libraries, that is.

Here's a jsfiddle with your code + YUI's mouseleave/enter events in action: http://jsfiddle.net/adHS8/

EDIT: jsfiddle.net code, with YUI 3.4.1 framework selected in the dropdown menu on the left:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #droplist {
        height:24px;
        overflow:hidden;
        border:1px solid black;
    }
    #droplist.open {
        height:auto;
        overflow:visible;
    }
        #droplist.open .stuff {
            border:1px solid red;
        }

</style>
<div id="droplist">
    <img src="http://aux4.iconpedia.net/uploads/8428095711397178883.png"  height="24" width="24" /><br />
     <div class="stuff">
        <input type="button" value="phone num" ><br />
        <input type="button" value="fax num" >
     </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
YUI().use(['event-mouseenter'], function (Y) {
    var droplist= Y.one('#droplist');

    droplist.on('mouseenter', function () {
        this.addClass('open');
    });

    droplist.on('mouseleave', function () {
        this.removeClass('open');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: jsfiddle.net seems to be broken... so I'll post the jsfiddle code I wrote and saw working a few minutes ago.